# How can I make Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code start with some template code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to have each Jupyter Notebook file start with some preexisting template code? For example, when I create a .ipynb file, the first cell would have some import statements of my choosing.

I looked through the Jupyter extension settings in VS Code, but I didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: I awarded the bounty to an answer but it seems they deleted it. Is there any way to recover the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Jupyter Notebooks' builtin mechanism for this. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files. Create `.py` or `.ipy` files in your `profile_default/startup/` directory (typically located within `~/.ipython/`), and they'll be run as soon as the IPython shell is created, and before your other code/scripts, in the order of their names. See also [the Jupyter docs on Python configuration files](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#python-configuration-files).

You will need to restart the kernel for the changes in those files to take effect. Use the restart button to restart the kernel, or the `Notebook: Restart Kernel` command in the command palette.

Answer (score -1):

This extension ([File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brpaz.file-templates#:%7E:text=In%20VSCode%2C%20right%20click%20on,the%20file%20will%20be%20created.)) should help.
Simply create a new .ipynb file and enter whatever imports and code you want to replicate, then use the command palette to select "New template from file". Then, whenever you need to create a new .ipynb file, go to the command palette, select, "New file from template" and select the appropriate template and you should be good to go.

This solution is not quite as simple, but it should take a similar amount of effort and is about as close as you can get.